# 7za remove all files of a type from a directory

Tags: p7zip

This seems like it would be a common thing to do, but I haven't found the answer. How do you remove all files of a certain type/extension from a zip archive using 7za?

The test zip file I am using:

```
7za l zipTestB.zip


   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------

2021-02-26 09:54:57 D....            0            0  testFolder

2021-02-26 09:53:47 ....A           46           71  testFolder/testC.txt

2021-02-26 09:54:06 ....A           53               testFolder/testD.txt

2021-02-26 09:53:00 ....A           18           35  testA.txt

2021-02-26 09:53:11 ....A           23               testB.txt

------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
```

It seems like this would work, but it only seems to remove testA.txt and testB.txt (first level files).

`7za d zipTestB.zip *.txt -r`

Comment: The man 7za page I found says of -r: "Recurse subdirectories (CAUTION: this flag does not do what you think, avoid using it)". It does not explain what it does do, or why the option exists if it is not to be used.

Comment: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/recurse.htm This link explains the `-r` option.